# Any subspace of the Sorgenfrey line is not homeomorph to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y\subset\mathbb{R}$ a subspace of the Sorgenfrey line $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_s)$, i.e, $Y$ is a topological space with the same topology $\tau_s$.

Show that $Y$ can't be homeomorph to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.

I try prove this suposse that yes are homeomorph and find a topological property that satisfied Sorgenfrey line but not $Y$ or viceversa. But i not can't find this property.

Comment: What about $Y=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Vinicius Novelli...is for any $Y\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then it's not true. If $Y=\mathbb{R}$, then it's homeomorphic to Sorgenfrey line. Did you mean a proper subspace?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something.  Isn't $\ln:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a homeomorphism with respect to the Sorgenfrey topology?  Because it's monotonic, it maps half closed intervals to half closed intervals.....

Comment: @Vinicius Novelli...yes is a proper subspace...sorry

Comment: @JasonDeVito Looks that way to me. The Sorgenfrey line is the topological sum of $\aleph_0$ homeomorphs of $[0,1)$ (with the Sorgenfrey topology), and so are all of its subspaces of the form $(a,b)$ or $[a,b)$, or so it seems to me. What am I missing.

Comment: Could it be a typo? Maybe the problem was to prove that the Sorgenfrey line isn't homeomorphic to any subspace of the real line with the usual topology?

Comment: see this... suppose that $Y\neq \emptyset$ is a subspace so that $\mathbb{R} \to Y$ is a homeomorphism. ($\mathbb{R}$ have the usual topology and $Y$ the topology of Sorgenfrey).  Let $a\in Y$ and consider the sequence $a_n=\{a-\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. In $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology $a_n\to 1$. In $Y$ not converges, if $(a_n)$ converges then converges to $a$,  why $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing then $a_n< a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Para $\epsilon>0$ the open $[a, a+\epsilon[$ not contains elements of the sequuence $(a_n)$ and for this not converge.

Comment: @bof...sorry the exercise is $Y$ can't be homeomorph to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology... sorry!!

Comment: @Vinicius Novelli...sorry...

Comment: How see my "solution" of exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sorgenfrey line $S$ is hereditarily disconnected: Any subspace $Y\subset S$ with more than one member is a disconnected space. For if $x,y\in Y$ with $x<y$ then $Y\cap (-\infty,y)$ and $Y\cap [y,\infty)$ are non-empty disjoint OPEN subsets of $Y$ whose union is $Y.$

Comment: The Sorgenfrey line is "strongly zero-dimensional". That is, it has a base (basis) of open-and-closed sets.